# Understanding assembly language _start label in a C program

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86, glibc

I had written a simple c program and was trying to do use GDB to debug the program. I understand the use of following in main function:

On entry

```
push   %ebp
mov    %esp,%ebp
```

On exit

```
leave
ret
```

Then I tried gdb on _start and I got the following

```
xor    %ebp,%ebp
pop    %esi
mov    %esp,%ecx
and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
push   %eax
push   %esp
push   %edx
push   $0x80484d0
push   $0x8048470
push   %ecx
push   %esi
push   $0x8048414
call   0x8048328 <__libc_start_main@plt>
hlt
nop
nop
nop
nop
```

I am unable to understand these lines, and the logic behind this.

Can someone provide any guidance to help explain the code of `_start`?

Comment: When compiling and linking with _GCC_  `_start` is is a label supplied by the _C_ runtime to do initialization. When the _C_ startup initialization is complete it makes a call to the label `main`. Maybe you intended to break on the label `main` rather than `_start`? The code you are seeing appears to be the _C_ runtime initialization code that eventually makes a call to `main`

Comment: The initialization code doesn't follow typical calling conventions, and also deals with the parameters passed on the command line per the Linux ABI, and massages them to so they can be passed to `main`. As well it makes sure the stack is properly aligned.

Comment: There's a really good tutorial of `_start` here: [`_start` is, oddly enough, where we start](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html#toc_link7)

Comment: @Michael Petch - thank you for this mind blowing document. I will go through it for sure

Comment: Actually, I can't take credit. The other Michael  - @MichaelBurr posted it ;-)

Comment: I can't take credit either. Patrick Horgan wrote the article, I just posted a link to it.

Comment: thanks to all !! : -)

Comment: Note that the initial process environment is defined by the ABI, so if you already knew the answer to your own question, you could have just looked for the ABI docs for 32bit Linux (see [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)).  Also note that in a dynamically-linked binary, the ELF interpreter runs before the first instruction in `_start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the well commented [assembly source](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/2a69f853c03034c2e383e0f9c35b5402ce8b5473/sysdeps/i386/start.S) of the code you posted.

Summarized, it does the following things:

1. establish a sentinel stack frame with ebp = 0 so code that walks the stack can find its end easily
2. Pop the number of command line arguments into `esi` so we can pass them to `__libc_start_main`
3. Align the stack pointer to a multiple of 16 bits in order to comply with the ABI. This is not guaranteed to be the case in some versions of Linux so it has to be done manually just in case.
4. The addresses of `__libc_csu_fini`, `__libc_csu_init`, the argument vector, the number of arguments and the address of `main` are pushed as arguments to `__libc_start_main`
5. `__libc_start_main` is called. This function (source code [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/2a69f853c03034c2e383e0f9c35b5402ce8b5473/sysdeps/x86/libc-start.c)) sets up some glibc-internal variables and eventually calls `main`. It never returns.
6. If for any reason `__libc_start_main` should return, a `hlt` instruction is placed afterwards. This instruction is not allowed in user code and should cause the program to crash (hopefully).
7. The final series of `nop` instructions is padding inserted by the assembler so the next function starts at a multiple of 16 bytes for better performance. It is never reached in normal execution.

Answer (score -2):

for gnu tools the _start label is the entry point of the program.  for the C language to work you need to have a stack you need to have some memory/variables zeroed and some set to the values you chose:

```
int x = 5;
int y;

int fun ( void )
{
   static int z;
}
```

all three of these variables x,y,z are essentially global, one is a local global.  since we wrote it that way we assume that when our program starts x contains the value 5 and it is assumed that y is zero.   in order for those things to happen, some bootstrap code is required and that is what happens (and more) between _start and main().

Other toolchains may choose to use a different label to define the entry/start point, but gnu tools use _start.  there may be other things your tools require before main() is called C++ for example requires more than C.

Comment: That's not at all what this code is doing. Note that zeroing global variables is not done by “some startup code.” In fact, it is likely not done at all. Rather, when the binary is mapped into RAM by the loader, anonymous pages are mapped for the BSS region described in the program headers. These are then mapped and zeroed out by the kernel on first use, but not earlier. I have downvoted your answer as it does not really answer the question at all.

Comment: and the logic behind this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your comment is trying to say.

Comment: Only dynamically-initialized things need constructors to run before `main()`.  FUZxxl is right: static initializers happen at compile time, and affect what's in the `.data` section.  (Or reserve space in the `.bss` if the initializer is zero).